# PHP is calling error on code that in not being run?

Tags: php

I was troubleshooting some code and I took it out of the execution path so that I could look in other places.

PHP continued to call out the code as an error despite it not being executed.  It is in a function that is not called.

Is this expected behavior?

```
// not in execution path

$temp1 = $this->hash;

$temp = array('1', $temp1); // this is line 121

$this->database_object->_pdoQuery('none', 'update_picture', $temp );
```

> syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ']' in
>   **/home/foo/public_html/dev/foo/source/class.MAppPicture.php**
>   on line **121**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on the line you marked, are you sure that's the real line 121?

Comment: Is that the actual code, or have you changed any variable names when you copied here? The error could be sensitive to the names of things.

Comment: You missed a `'` in `$this->file_hash = $pipe['client']['file_hash];` (look at the syntax highlighting provided on this site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire file has to be parsed prior at the time of access or include. This is generating an error because it is a parse time error and php can't understand the file as a whole because of the syntax error.

Comment: ...ended up just commenting everything out to troubleshoot.

Comment: In this specific case I would expect you have a line with something like `$foo['bar]` somewhere above (note the missing `'`, so from your `'1'` the first `'`will finish the key name and then the engine expects a closing `]` but sees an `1`)

Comment: And if you're using an editor with syntax highlighting, it should be pretty easy to see where this is happening.

Comment: The error, most likely, is above the lines you've shown. Scroll the file up to the previous usage of single quotes (`'`), most likely you've missed one in a construct like `$foo['bar']`.